# Odds and Rate Ratio CIs in Hurdle Models with Factor-Factor Interactions

Tags: confidence-interval, glmmtmb

I am trying to build hurdle models with factor-factor interactions but can't figure out how to calculate the CIs of the odds or rate ratios among the various factor-factor combinations.

```
library(glmmTMB)
data(Salamanders)
m3 <- glmmTMB(count ~ spp + mined + spp * mined,
              zi=~spp + mined + spp * mined,
              family=truncated_poisson, data=Salamanders) # added in the interaction
pred_dat <- data.frame(spp = rep(unique(Salamanders$spp), 2),
                       mined = rep(unique(Salamanders$mined), each = length(unique(Salamanders$spp))))
pred_dat # All factor-factor combos
```

Does anyone know how to appropriately calculate the CI around the ratios among these various factor-factor combos? I know how to calculate the actual ratio estimates (which consists of exponentiating the sum of 1-3 model coefficients, depending on the exact comparison being made) but I just can't seem to find any info on how to get the corresponding CI when an interaction is involved. If the ratio in question only requires exponentiating a single coefficient, the CI can easily be calculated; I just don't know how to do it when two or three coefficients are involved in calculating the ratio. Any help would be much appreciated.

EDIT:
I need the actual odds and rate ratios and their CIs, not the predicted values and their CIs. For example: exp(confint(m3)[2,3]) gives the rate ratio of sppPR/minedYes vs sppGP/minedYes, and c(exp(confint(m3)[2,1]),exp(confint(m3)[2,2]) gives the CI of that rate ratio. However, a number of the potential comparisons among the spp/mined combinations require summing multiple coefficients e.g., exp(confint(m3)[2,3] + confint(m3)[8,3]) but in these circumstances I do not know how to calculate the rate ratio CI because it involves multiple coefficients, each of which has its own SE estimates. How can I calculate those CIs, given that multiple coefficients are involved?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this would be one way to obtain the uncertainty around the predicted/fitted values of the interaction term:

```r
library(glmmTMB)
library(ggeffects)

data(Salamanders)
m3 <- glmmTMB(count ~ spp + mined + spp * mined,
              zi=~spp + mined + spp * mined,
              family=truncated_poisson, data=Salamanders) # added in the interaction

ggpredict(m3, c("spp", "mined"))
#> 
#> # Predicted counts of count
#> # x = spp
#> 
#> # mined = yes
#> 
#> x    | Predicted |   SE |       95% CI
#> --------------------------------------
#> GP   |      1.59 | 0.92 | [0.26, 9.63]
#> PR   |      1.13 | 0.66 | [0.31, 4.10]
#> DM   |      1.74 | 0.29 | [0.99, 3.07]
#> EC-A |      0.61 | 0.96 | [0.09, 3.96]
#> EC-L |      0.42 | 0.69 | [0.11, 1.59]
#> DF   |      1.49 | 0.27 | [0.88, 2.51]
#> 
#> # mined = no
#> 
#> x    | Predicted |   SE |       95% CI
#> --------------------------------------
#> GP   |      2.67 | 0.11 | [2.15, 3.30]
#> PR   |      1.59 | 0.28 | [0.93, 2.74]
#> DM   |      3.10 | 0.10 | [2.55, 3.78]
#> EC-A |      2.30 | 0.17 | [1.64, 3.21]
#> EC-L |      5.25 | 0.07 | [4.55, 6.06]
#> DF   |      2.68 | 0.12 | [2.13, 3.36]
#> Standard errors are on link-scale (untransformed).
plot(ggpredict(m3, c("spp", "mined")))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The [ggeffects-package](http://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects) calculates marginal effects / estimates marginal means (EMM) with confidence intervals for your model terms. `ggpredict()` computes these EMMs based on `predict()`, `ggemmeans()` wraps the fantastic *emmeans* package and `ggeffect()` uses the *effects* package.

Comment: This isn't exactly what I am looking for: please see my edit above.

Comment: I think that what I wrote in my answer gives you exactly what you're looking for, however, _on the response scale_. If you are looking for the rate ratios, you need to multiply the rate ratios for the coefficients in question, and the SE/CI can probably be calculated using some delta-method (not sure, though, how to exactly do this).

Comment: As I mentioned previously, I am specifically looking for the **CIs** of the odds and rate ratios - so I guess code for the delta-method would be what I need.